# Tracker not indexing file contents

Tags: gnome, search, 17.10, tracker

I am new to Ubuntu and gnome3...

I have a clean install of 17.10 and activated the shell extensions (tracker-search and tracker-search-provider).

But when I search something (don't know, how the overview is called that opens when I press "super") the results are only files with the search term in its name.

Isn't tracker supposed to index the file contents as well (pdf, txt, md, doc etc.)? And how can I enable it?

**Note**: I am making small newbie-steps... In Nautilus the search works as expected. Is the overview called "dash"? And do I need a "lens" though it's not unity?

Comment: I am making small newbie-steps... In Nautilus the search works as expected. Is the overview called "dash"? And do I need a "lens" though it's not unity?

Answer (score 0):

The extensions you mention are old and not anymore updated for newer Gnome Shell versions. You should remove them.

By design, Gnome Shell should currently be able to provide you with search results from tracker. For that, it relies on nautilus search which in turn can use tracker. It is very well possible that in practice, though, full text search through Gnome Shell still does not work. After all, it is only since a couple of months that simple file name based search started to work in Gnome Shell coming with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Did anyone actually manage to get it to work ? Using Ubuntu 18.04 + tracker, it takes an hour and a half to index my data. I had to remove a specific file which would cause tracker to eat my CPU forever. When it's over, I always get a strange result when typing "tracker daemon" : the first entry, "Store" is indicated as "0%" "idle" while the 3 last entries (collectors) are indicated as over. The search yields no result although "tracker status" tells 100 000 files or so were indexed. Restarting the OS restarts the whole indexing process. A complete tracker reset made no difference. Any idea ?